# Dual of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality-theorems, bochner-spaces, dual-spaces

A linear operator $A$ is defined from $L^2(0,T)$ to $C([0,T);\mathbb{H})$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is a Hilbert space. At some point, dual of this operator is needed; a detour to calculate the dual, and avoid dealing with dual space of continuous functions is to have $A$ as an operator from $L^2(0,T)$ to $L^2([0,T);\mathbb{H})$. Now consider $f\in L^2(0,T)$ and $w\in L^2([0,T);\mathbb{H})$ for which

$$\langle Af,w\rangle_{L^2([0,T);\mathbb{H})}=\langle f,A^*w\rangle_{L^2(0,T)}$$

coincides with

$$\langle f,Bw\rangle_{L^2(0,T)}$$

for a $B:L^2([0,T);\mathbb{H})\to L^2(0,T)$. Is this true to expect that $B=A^*:C([0,T);\mathbb{H})\to L^2(0,T)$?

Comment: I am unclear on what you are asking. How are you defining $V:=C([0,T);\mathbb H)$? All continuous functions? Or just bounded ones? You require the latter (or some restriction) for this space to be Banach, but even then it is not a Hilbert space so $A^*$ does not act on $V$. You could consider $(V,H,V^*)$ as a Gelfand triple where $H=L^2((0,T);\mathbb H)$, in which case I suppose you might be asking whether $A^*w=Bw$ for all $w\in V$, but then the answer is trivially "yes" by your definition. It would be helpful for you to clarify your question.

Comment: The space $C([0,T);\mathbb{H})$ refers to Bochner space equipped with the norm $\|w\|_{C([0,T);\mathbb{H})}=\max_{t\in [0,T)}\|w(t)\|_{\mathbb{H}}$

Comment: That's not a Bochner space, that's a continuous function space. Moreover, if you mean to include *all* continuous functions $w:[0,T)\to\mathbb H$ then $\|w\|_{C([0,T);\mathbb H)}$ need not be finite, so this is not a norm.